# Copy contacts from public folders to each user on Exchange 365 using EWS?

Tags: exchangewebservices

This question has been asked, and answered, multiple times but all have involved a on prem Exchange server and I cannot find a answer for Exchange 365.  We are trying to keep a list of cell phone numbers updated within a sub directory of each persons contacts folder so that their cell phones see them.  In the on prem days we ran a powershell command to import the contents of a PST into each user and inside that PST was a single folder under contacts called "Cell Phone List".  Then once a month we ran a script like this to delete any contact with our company name and re-import the updated list:

```
Search-Mailbox -Identity (alias) -SearchQuery 'kind:contacts AND subject:" - CompanyName"' -DeleteContent -Force
Search-Mailbox -Identity (alias) -SearchQuery 'kind:contacts' -SearchDumpsterOnly -DeleteContent
New-MailboxImportRequest -Mailbox (alias) -FilePath "\\FileServer\Share\CellPhoneContacts.pst" -TargetRootFolder "#Contacts#"
```

This worked great until we migrated to Exchange 365.  At that point there was no way to delete the contacts.  A compliance search works to get a list of the contacts but the compliance search action for purge doesn't work on contacts.  We put in support tickets with Microsoft and the end result was it can't be done, you can search and delete emails but not contacts.  They said they would add it as a feature request though....

So what we did was pulled the cell phone list into a public folder.  We gave people instructions on going into Contacts\Cell Phone List within their Outlook, deleting all the contacts, then going up to the public folder, selecting everything, right click and dragging it to their "Cell Phone List" folder, and copying.  This is a work around and does what it needs to do but we would like a better automated solution.  I checked around to some major software companies like CodeTwo but none have this ability.  So I will have to do this through EWS.  There are examples of adding the contacts ( https://www.independentsoft.de/exchangewebservices/tutorial/createcontactwithpicture.html ) but I'm having a hard time finding a example of copying existing contacts.  If I have to I can export out the cell phone list as a CSV file, add a ID field, and save all the pictures to a filename the same as the ID and then reimport them but this seems like a huge waste of time since they already exist.

Is there anything in EWS that lets me a) Delete all contacts either in a folder or with a certain subject like what I used to do on prem and b) allow me to copy contacts from a public folder to each users mailbox?  I have successfully created a EWS app using token authentication and have been able to poll the inbox of a mailbox successfully so I feel the hardest part is out of the way but I can't figure out the contacts part.

Answer (score 0):

Both EWS and Public Folders are two legacy solutions so I wouldn't suggest you use either of these as it may just break in the future.

> Is there anything in EWS that lets me a) Delete all contacts either in a folder or with a certain subject like what I used to do on prem

You can use the Empty folder method in EWS https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/gg274404(v=exchg.80) or if you want to search by subject you would need to use FindItems and DeleteItems.

> b) allow me to copy contacts from a public folder to each users
> mailbox?

EWS does allow you to copy across stores using the CopyItem operation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-move-and-copy-email-messages-by-using-ews-in-exchange

However in the Cloud you may find the two stores are in different datacentre's so that can make it a bit fragile.

When you are using EWS with Public folder you need to make sure you get the Routing headers correct else it generally won't work well. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-route-public-folder-content-requests, I've got one example of that https://github.com/gscales/Powershell-Scripts/blob/master/EnumerateItemsInPublicFolder.ps1

> We are trying to keep a list of cell phone numbers updated within a
> sub directory of each persons contacts folder so that their cell
> phones see them.

What is your source data in ? eg if its just a CSV (or could be a CSV) why not just create a script using the Graph API. It relatively straight forward to create a new contact in a Folder eg https://practical365.com/prepopulating-outlook-contacts-with-the-graph-api/.

To Delete the contacts you just need to enumerate (or filter/search) and Delete eg in the Graph SDK

```
$Folder = Get-MgUserContactFolder -UserId xx@blah.onmicrosoft.com -Filter "displayName eq 'TestImport'"
$Contacts = Get-MgUserContact -UserId xx@blah.onmicrosoft.com -All
```

The delete each contact use its id

```
Remove-MgUserContact -UserId $userId -ContactId $contactId
```

If there are a lot of contacts involved you want batch the process to make sure the script runs at a decent speed and you avoid throttling(which is probably the biggest challenge using the Graph to do this).

Comment: So the main issue is the contacts are currently in a PST folder.  I can export them to CSV but there is a picture with each one which is the main issue I'm running into which is why I'm looking to copy existing.  In total we are looking at 220 contacts.

Comment: I would store the contacts as Vcard files in a directory which would include the photo and give you the option of editing them when necessary.  Then create a script that syncs the Vcards back into the Mailboxes. But the easiest option if the New-MailboxImportRequest still works okay for you then just use the Graph or EWS to do the deletes, in both cases you won't be able to delete things from the dumpster with EWS or the Graph as these are client API they need to comply with the business logic around retention.

Comment: Yeah, that's the other issue.  New-MailboxImportRequest is a on prem only command now, they removed it from 365.  It's like they are going backwards.  I did find a article about importing PST files (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/use-network-upload-to-import-pst-files) but it doesn't look sustainable with frequent updates.  I may have to give up having photos and go with a straight CSV file.